# Best splittable compression for Hadoop input = bz2?

Tags: hadoop, gzip, hdfs, bzip2

We've realized a bit too late that archiving our files in GZip format for Hadoop processing isn't such a great idea. GZip isn't splittable, and for reference, here are the problems which I won't repeat:

- [Very basic question about Hadoop and compressed input files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2078850/very-basic-question-about-hadoop-and-compressed-input-files)
- [Hadoop gzip compressed files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5630245/hadoop-gzip-compressed-files)
- [Hadoop gzip input file using only one mapper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7388436/hadoop-gzip-input-file-using-only-one-mapper)
- [Why can't hadoop split up a large text file and then compress the splits using gzip?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6511255/why-cant-hadoop-split-up-a-large-text-file-and-then-compress-the-splits-using-g)

My question is: is BZip2 the best archival compression that will allow a single archive file to be processed in parallel by Hadoop? Gzip is definitely not, and from my reading LZO has some problems.

Comment: Snappy is the default compression algorithm used by Spark for Parquet files and is another great option.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

**BZIP2** is splittable in hadoop - it provides very good compression ratio but from CPU time and performances is not providing optimal results, as compression is very CPU consuming.

**LZO** is splittable in hadoop - leveraging **[hadoop-lzo](https://github.com/twitter/hadoop-lzo)** you have splittable compressed LZO files. You need to have external .lzo.index files to be able to process in parallel. The library provides all means of generating these indexes in local or distributed manner.

**LZ4** is splittable in hadoop - leveraging **[hadoop-4mc](https://github.com/carlomedas/4mc)** you have splittable compressed 4mc files. You don't need any external indexing, and you can generate archives with provided command line tool or by Java/C code, inside/outside hadoop. 4mc makes available on hadoop LZ4 at any level of speed/compression-ratio: from fast mode reaching 500 MB/s compression speed up to high/ultra modes providing increased compression ratio, almost comparable with GZIP one.

Comment: I prefer LZ4 myself these days.

Comment: surprised you left out Zlib.

Comment: @nikk zstd's initial release was in 2015, the post dates back to 2014.

Answer (score 6):

Here are five ways with gzip, three needing an index, two not.

It is possible to create an index for any gzip file, i.e. not specially constructed, as done by [zran.c](https://github.com/madler/zlib/blob/master/examples/zran.c). Then you can start decompression at block boundaries. The index includes the 32K of uncompressed data history at each entry point.

If you are constructing the gzip file, then it can be made with periodic entry points whose index does not need uncompressed history at those entry points, making for a smaller index. This is done with the `Z_FULL_FLUSH` option to `deflate()` in zlib.

You could also do a `Z_SYNC_FLUSH` followed by a `Z_FULL_FLUSH` at each such point, which would insert two markers. Then you can search for the nine-byte pattern `00 00 ff ff 00 00 00 ff ff` to find those. That's no different than searching for the six-byte marker in bzip2 files, except that a false positive is much less likely with nine bytes. Then you don't need a separate index file.

Both gzip and xz support simple concatenation.  This allows you to easily prepare an archive for parallel decompression in another way.  In short:

```
gzip < a > a.gz
gzip < b > b.gz
cat a.gz b.gz > c.gz
gunzip < c.gz > c
cat a b | cmp - c
```

will result in the compare succeeding.

You can then simply compress in chunks of the desired size and concatenate the results.  Save an index to the offsets of the start of each gzip stream.  Decompress from those offsets.  You can pick the size of the chunks to your liking, depending on your application.  If you make them too small however, compression will be impacted.

With simple concatenation of gzip files, you could also forgo the index if you made each chunk a fixed uncompressed size. Then each chunk ends with the same four bytes, the uncompressed length in little-endian order, e.g. `00 00 10 00` for 1 MiB chunks, followed by `1f 8b 08` from the next chunk, which is the start of a gzip header. That seven-byte marker can then be searched for just like the bzip2 marker, though again with a smaller probability of false positives.

The same could be done with concatenated xz files, whose header is the seven bytes: `fd 37 7a 58 5a 00 00`.

Comment: Thanks! How is it possible to prepare gzip/bzip2 files and make them splittable with entry points?

Comment: Tip: since I didn't find hadoop fs -bzcat , instead use: hadoop fs -cat /FILENAME.bz | bzcat | less

Comment: According to this http://comphadoop.weebly.com/ bzip2 IS splittable but gzip is not.

Comment: I don't think this is actually answering the question. Splittable means something very specific in the Hadoop world, and GZIP is NOT splittable.

Comment: @davideanastasia: gzip can be splittable if you want it to be. See updated answer.

Answer (score 6):

I don't consider the other answer correct, bzip2 according to this:

http://comphadoop.weebly.com/

is splittable.  LZO is too *if indexed*.

So the answer is yes, if you want to use more mappers than you have files, then you'll want to use bzip2.

To do this, you could write a simple MR job to read the data then just write it out again, you then need to ensure you set `mapred.output.compression.codec` to `org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.BZip2Codec`

Comment: I would go with this answer, but it would be much better if you would also give us the HOW: How can I create indexed bz2 files?

Comment: @Gavriel I don't know how to create *indexed LZO*, but I'll update my answer to briefly explain how to compress to bzip2.

Comment: (Well I write my output via gzip compression, because that's what RedShift can read) but will any correct bzip2 file do as input, or do I need to pass some special parameter to have the blocks / indexes?

Comment: You don't need indexing with bzip2, just LZO. Most Big Data tools handle all sorts of compression automatically by looking at the file ending.

Answer (score 1):

My 2cents, bzip is very slow for writing. Tested with Apache Spark 1.6.2, Hadoop 2.7, compresse a simple JSON file of 50Go, it takes 2x time with bzip than gzip.

But with bzip, 50Go ==> 4 Go!